# MySQL: gets the id instead of the value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database.
Men table:

```
+----------------------------------------
| ID | menname              | partner   |
+----------------------------------------
| 1  | Mark                 | 1         |
| 2  | Adam                 | 2         |
----------------------------------------+
```

Women table:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| ID | womenname                        |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | Lisa                             |
| 2  | Emma                             |
+---------------------------------------+
```

When I do a inner join, I get:

```
+----------------------------------------
| ID | menname              | partner   |
+----------------------------------------
| 1  | Mark                 | 1         |
| 2  | Adam                 | 2         |
----------------------------------------+
```

instead of:

```
+----------------------------------------
| ID | menname              | partner   |
+----------------------------------------
| 1  | Mark                 | Lisa      |
| 2  | Adam                 | Emma      |
----------------------------------------+
```

It gets the id, instead of the partner name.
Anyone know what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Maybe post your query so we can tell for sure instead of guess?

Comment: Use `women.womenname` instead of `women.id` in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.ID
        ,m.menname
        ,w.womenname AS partner
FROM    Men AS m
        INNER JOIN Women AS w ON m.partner = w.ID;
```